# how working with view and controller

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to learn how CakePHP works but i'm stuck, i just want to display the user names . I'm working in the good controller and the good view... I don't understand .

View => Users => index.ctp

```
<h1>Users List</h1> <table>

    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>

    </tr>

   <?php foreach ($users as $k): ?>

    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $k['username']; ?></td> 

    </tr> 

    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    </table>
```

Controller => UsersController

```
    <?php
    class UsersController extends AppController{

        public function index() {
        $users = $this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('id','username','created')));
        debug($users);
        }

    }
    ?>
```

With debug, i have what i want but i can't display the result in my table with foreach .

```
 array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'username' => 'CREAZ',
                'created' => '2014-06-17 23:39:52'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'username' => 'test2',
                'created' => '2014-06-18 16:57:37'
            )
        )
    )
```

The errors i get in my view :

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: users [APP\View\Users\index.ctp, line 9]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Users\index.ctp, line 9]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: users [APP\View\Users\index.ctp, line 13]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Users\index.ctp, line 13]
```

Comment: check [cake's blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#create-a-posts-controller), you are missing the important step of passing the data from the controller to the view (I left the link exactly where you have to read for that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I understand that i have to create a controller for each view, i have to do something else ?

Comment: yes: "passing the data from the controller to the view"... the code is right in the link I gave in the comment before.

Comment: Yes i read it but i don't understand what i have to add in my code . You mean the variable $helper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the users variable in the controller first as shown below:

```
  <?php
    class UsersController extends AppController{

        public function index() {
        $users = $this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('id','username','created')));
        debug($users);
        $this->set('users', $users);
        }

    }
    ?>
```

and in the view index.ctp, do it like below:

```
<h1>Users List</h1> 
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>

    </tr>

   <?php foreach ($users as $k): ?>

    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $k['User']['username']; ?></td> 

    </tr> 

    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    </table>
```